Calculating width for non perfectly aligned polygon in ArcGIS Pro
I have a non perfectly aligned polygon feature (blue) for which I want to calculate the minimal width:

Now when I run the “minimum boundary geometry”-tool in ArcGIS Pro, the area for which the width is calculated (yellow), is substantially different than the original area (blue) due to the polygon being not perfectly aligned. I want to calculate the minimal width of only the non perfectly aligned however.
the suggested solution to a similar question at Calculating minimum width of polygon using ArcMap obtains a minimal width but with some inaccuracy, or obtains a minimal width with high(er) accuracy but with the cost of potentially large data.
Therefore, I am wondering if there might be an alternative approach that costs less data and/or has more accuracy on the minimal width.

Your question has been asked several times before, for example Calculating minimum width of polygon using ArcMap.

The suggested solution provides an option to obtain the minimum width, however the northern and southern points are not perfectly aligned i.e. does not reflect the actual minimal width. The accuracy on the minimal width increases when the number of added points increase, however this potentially results in very large data; there might be an alternative approach that costs less data and/or has more accuracy on the minimal width.

@BERA I edited the question to include your reference.

Shortest line always goes through vertex:

So generate near table with location and limit search to 2 features. Remove rows with NEAR_DIST=0 and find row with minimum value:

You can actually do near table for 2 lines - on itsef- and default parameters, which will result in 2 lines of identical length:

